# p:dataTable does not render inside carousel and tab components

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Environment:
 - PrimeFaces version: 5.0

I'm trying to include a `p:carousel`
 in my application, but the `p:dataTable` appears as a blank in the `p:tab` view. The following is a simplified example. The facelets template page is:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/> 
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/> 
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/style.css"/> 
    <title>Test Template</title>
</h:head>

 <h:body>
    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

  </h:body>
```

The carousel JSF page:

```
<body>

 <ui:composition template="./ClientNav.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="content">
 <h:form>
 <p:carousel numVisible="1" autoPlayInterval="20000" effect="easeInStrong" 
 headerText="Contents" style="margin-bottom: 0" circular="true">

 <p:tab>

 <h1>Heading</h1>
 <p>Text of the first tab view</p>

 <p:graphicImage name="images/enterBlank.jpg" alt="sky" width="1000" height="252"/>
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab>                          
  <p:dataTable value="#{topicbean.pubTopList}" var="top">
  <p:column>
  <p:commandLink value="#{top.topicname}" action="#{topicbean.searchGuestItems}"
                                               ajax="false"/>
   </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   </p:tab>        

   </p:carousel>
   </h:form>
   </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

If i replace p:dataTable with h:dataTable it renders perfectly. I also tested an ordinary JSF page (without templating) using the p dataTable and the same problem (no rendering) happened. Finally I tried to strip the carousel component to the bare minimum (in case any setting were causing css conflict):

```
<p:carousel numVisible="1">
tabs here
</p:carousel>
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm missing something in my code or how I'm using the carousel. Would appreciate any guidance. Thank you.

Comment: 5 is 5.0? Tried newer versions?

Comment: My apologies. I missed the zero in my title. Edited now. I tried an 5.2.which had the same issue but finally got it to show with 5.3 (although it still has some css issues like the scroll bar not showing). Before upgrading I wanted to see if I was missing anything in my use of these components. I'll try fixing the remaining issues and update the post.Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Better to always create an [mcve] and then try with newer versions (and check the releasenotes, blog and issuelist (open AND closed issues) before posting.

Comment: will do. Thanks again